# Initialize another variable or use the original over and over

Tags: c++, memory-management

This is happening to me a lot during the making of this program and i thought it was better to ask you guys.

For example, if I have a loop that calls a specific structure of a vector, is it better to call the vector over and over like this:

```
FP_list[n].callsign=...
FP_list[n].de_airport=...
FP_list[n].ar_airport=...;
FP_list[n].aircraft_type=...
FP_list[n].trueairspeed=...
FP_list[n].FL_route.push_back(Aircraft.GetClearedAltitude());
FP_list[n].last_WP=...
FP_list[n].next_WP=...
```

...

Or to declare a temporary variable and use it from that point on like this:

```
FP temp=FP_list[n];
temp.callsign=...
...
temp.next_WP=...
```

Which one it better in terms of memory consumption and running time?

Thank you in advance

Comment: "Which one it better in terms of memory consumption and running time?" Depends on the type of FP. In general, taking a reference is faster. I notice FP contains a data structure with push_back, so I would avoid copying it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Efficiency is a trade-off.  The way you wrote the code, it is making a copy of the structure.   Depending on how expensive making that copy is, it may be far worse than the extra time to evaluate the index expression.

My conclusion:  Write the code as cleanly as possible so it is obvious what it is doing, then let the optimizer in the compiler worry about efficiency.   If performance does become an issue, then profile first so you can be sure you are hand-optimizing the right problem.

Comment: This is the kind of answer i was looking for. @Danvil Thank you for your answer and for alerting me to use reference

Answer (score 5):

If `FP_list` is an `std::vector` or similar you can do:

```
FP& p = FP_list[n];
 ^^^ use a reference
p.callsign = ...;
p.de_airport = ...;
p.ar_airport = ...;
```

This code uses a reference to access the data. A reference gives you direct access to the element it refers. It works a bit like a pointer. Now you have to call `operator[]` only once, and your code is much more compact.

As noted in the comments, be careful that references might by invalidated if you make changes to the vector itself, e.g. adding or removing elements.

This assumes you actually want to change the contents stored in the vector. If you do not want to change them, you have to create a copy: `FP p = FP_list[n];`.

Comment: "This way operator[] is evaluated only once." That's better in terms of memory and running time right?

Comment: Excellent suggestion, but you should mention the reference may become invalid if any change is made to the vector -- even adding a new element at the end may force the vector to reallocate the buffer where its contents are stored.

Comment: @JoãoPereira, if you do `FP temp=FP_list[n]` you actually create a temporary object. However, @Danvil proposes to use a reference to point to the same `FP_list[n]` object, and this way you save the referencing of the 'nth' element of the vector. In addition, it looks cleaner.

Comment: cnluzon is right - to expound, the temp object will then be destroyed without any changes having affected FP_list[n] - you really must use a reference

Comment: I agree, except for the last sentence. If you don't want to make a copy, a const reference is also a possibility.

Comment: @NeilKirk: From OP's question it was not clear if he wants to change the elements stored in the vector or not. If he wants to use a copy, change it and use it somewhere else, a const reference won't work.

Comment: Yes i forgot to say but i want to change the elements, so a reference is needed

Comment: OP I suggest using pointers (raw or preferably smart) in the vector, especially if copying is expensive. Then you would declare a pointer of the type that's in the vector, and your 'temporary variable' option would then work as well.